# Firefox css issue

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

I was trying to implement Firefox specific CSS using this code:

```
  @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
      #orbit-inside img.orbit-slide {
          width:100%!important;
          max-width:100%!important;
          height:auto;
          margin-top: 30px;
      }
 }
```

But this not working on Fx, can I know why this is not working?

The site I was implementing http://trichometechnology.com/ (the header slider).

I need a top margin in Fx because there is contact no which other browsers are showing and the problem is only with firefox.

Comment: when you need to hack for a specific browser, you probably doing something wrong. turn CSS one by one back on again to find what you did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me (Firefox 14.0.1 on Win XP)

Anyway, you don't need to add a margin if you add

```
.custom-slider{clear:both;}
```

Remember to clear after floating elements!